# How to detect if a user comes from facebook or directly

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-page, iframe-app

let's say I have a website, which I'm also using as a facebook app (iframed page tab of a facebook page).
I need to know if the user has opened my site via the facebook app, or not, as I want to change some css and content only if opened in facebook.

Afaik I only get signed_request the first time the user opens the iframe on fb, so I "lose" it after the user navigates on my site.
Is there a better way to do this other than storing the signed_request in session?

Thanks in advance